# pytorch "log_softmax_lastdim_kernel_impl" not implemented for 'torch.LongTensor'

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use my own dataset to classify text according to https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/5%20-%20Multi-class%20Sentiment%20Analysis.ipynb. My dataset is a csv of sentences and a class associated with it. there are 6 different classes:

```
sent                      class
'the fox is brown'        animal
'the house is big'        object
'one water is drinkable'  water
...
```

When running:

```
N_EPOCHS = 5

best_valid_loss = float('inf')

for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

    start_time = time.time()
    print(start_time)
    train_loss, train_acc = train(model, train_iterator, optimizer, criterion)
    print(train_loss.type())
    print(train_acc.type())
    valid_loss, valid_acc = evaluate(model, valid_iterator, criterion)

    end_time = time.time()

    epoch_mins, epoch_secs = epoch_time(start_time, end_time)

    if valid_loss < best_valid_loss:
        best_valid_loss = valid_loss
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'tut5-model.pt')

    print(f'Epoch: {epoch+1:02} | Epoch Time: {epoch_mins}m {epoch_secs}s')
    print(f'\tTrain Loss: {train_loss:.3f} | Train Acc: {train_acc*100:.2f}%')
    print(f'\t Val. Loss: {valid_loss:.3f} |  Val. Acc: {valid_acc*100:.2f}%')
```

, I receive the following error

```
RuntimeError: "log_softmax_lastdim_kernel_impl" not implemented for 'torch.LongTensor'
```

pointing to:

```
<ipython-input-38-9c6cff70d2aa> in train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion)
     14         print('pred'+ predictions.type())
     15         #batch.label = batch.label.type(torch.LongTensor)
---> 16         loss = criterion(predictions.long(), batch.label)**
```

The solution posted here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14224 suggests I need to use long/int.

I had to add `.long()` at line `**` in order to fix this earlier error:

`RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target'`

The specific lines of code are:

```
  def train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion):
    epoch_loss = 0
    epoch_acc = 0

    model.train()

    for batch in iterator:

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        predictions = model(batch.text)
        print('pred'+ predictions.type())
        #batch.label = batch.label.type(torch.LongTensor)
        loss = criterion(predictions.long(), batch.label)**

        acc = categorical_accuracy(predictions, batch.label)

        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        epoch_acc += acc.item()

    return epoch_loss / len(iterator), epoch_acc / len(iterator)
```

Note, the ** was originally `loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)`

Any other suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`criterion` is defined as `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` in your [notebook](https://github.com/bentrevett/pytorch-sentiment-analysis/blob/master/5%20-%20Multi-class%20Sentiment%20Analysis.ipynb). As mentioned in documentation of [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), it expects probability values returned by model for each of the 'K' classes and corresponding value for ground-truth label as input. Now, probability values are float tensors, while ground-truth label should be a long tensor representing a class (class can not be a float, e.g. 2.3 can not represent a class). hence:

```
loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label.long())
```

should work.

Comment: thanks, I tried to convert the type earlier with .type(torch.LongTensor) but this lead to an error as well, so I discounted it.

Answer (score 0):

if using gpu, instead of defining the long type under loss criterion, you should probably define it before using cuda. I face the same error. resolved it with below:

```
 # move data to GPU, if available
    if train_on_gpu:
        inp = inp.cuda()
        target = target.long()
        target=target.cuda()
    h = tuple([each.data for each in hidden])
    # perform backpropagation and optimization

    #zero accumulated gradient
    rnn.zero_grad()

    #getting out_put from model
    output,h = rnn(inp,h)
    #calculating loss and performing back_propagation

    loss = criterion(output.squeeze(), target)
```

Answer (score 0):

CrossEntropyLoss(**pred**, **target**), takes **FloatTensor pred** and **LongTensor target**; so, make sure your variable tensor types are congruent with the expected types.